# Assign a class to a css attribute selector

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI with ASP MVC3 to build some forms. I am using the dropdown and datepicker widgets, which are styled larger that standard inputs. To ensure standard textboxes will match, Kendo has provided the `.k-textbox` class, which when assigned to a textbox, will style it to match the widgets.

I have created a template that does the job but is requiring a little extra coding to handle some conflicts, no biggie.  However, I was wondering if there was a way to make an attribute selector (eg: `input[type="text"]`) inherit the style from another styled class.  So could I make `input[type=:text"]` use the same styles as `.k-textbox`, without copying all the class data over?

Comment: Ok I am just going to use a template.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your selector to the existing one, separated by a comma:

```
.k-textbox, input[type="text"] {
   /* classes already written by Kendo */
}
```

but then you won't be able to easily update this CSS when Kendo updates it.

Comment: Unfortunately kendo has the styles for k-textbox spread over 17 or so different places.

Comment: 30 occurences in my copy of commons.min.css, yep :/ Still possible with regexp at least in Sublime Text but a bit complicated (you've to capture what is between k-textbox and the next comma and add it to your selector too...)